# wx.TextCtrl has blue outline but won't receive text in wxMac

Tags: python, cocoa, wxpython, wxwidgets, osx-mountain-lion

I have been writing a printer driver backend for Linux and Mac that displays a window allowing the user to select a printer. Part of the process is for the user to input Username and Password for authentication. It all works great on Linux. However, I have a strange issue. When I run the script on OSX Mountain Lion as a normal user, it works fine. However, when I run it through the CUPS backend (as user _lp), the username and password boxes suddenly will not receive text, despite being selected. Part of this is that the application will not generate on top of all windows either.

I have searched and read about how Macs need a .app bundle, but even after trying that, it didn't solve my issue. Here is my LoginWindow class:

```
class LoginDialog(wx.Dialog):
  def __init__(self, parent, id=-1, title="Login",
        pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
        size=wx.Size(350, 150),
        style=wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ):
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size, style)
    wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Please enter your CAEDM username and password.',
        wx.Point(15,5))
    wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Username:', wx.Point(20, 32))
    wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Password: ', wx.Point(25, 57))
    self.nameBox = wx.TextCtrl(self, 1, 'password', wx.Point(100, 30),
        wx.Size(170, -1))
    self.passwordBox = wx.TextCtrl(self, 2, '', wx.Point(100, 55),
        wx.Size(170, -1), style=wx.TE_PASSWORD)
    self.btnOK = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK, ' OK ', wx.Point(60, 90),
        wx.DefaultSize)
    self.btnOK.SetDefault()
    self.btnCancel = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CANCEL, ' Cancel ', wx.Point(160, 90),
        wx.DefaultSize)
    self.https_user = []


def https_bind(self):
    val = self.ShowModal()
    self.SetFocus()
    if val == wx.ID_OK:
        u = self.nameBox.GetValue()
        p = self.passwordBox.GetValue()
        #since the username passed by CUPS is trash, we have to re-invent it (authenticate against HTTPS) 


        try:
            os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = RESOURCE_DIR + '/cacert.pem'
            cert = requests.get("https://lp.et.byu.edu/pa/submit.php", auth=(u, p) )
            print cert.status_code
            if ( cert.status_code == 200 ):
                self.https_user.append(u)
                self.https_user.append(p)
            else:
                d = ErrorDialog(self)
                d.SetTitleText("Server Error")
                d.SetLabelText("         Username or password incorrect.")
                d.ShowModal()
                self.https_bind()

        except:
            d = ErrorDialog(self)
            d.SetTitleText("Server Error")
            d.SetLabelText("         Username or password incorrect.")
            d.ShowModal()
            self.https_bind()

    if val == wx.ID_CANCEL:
        os._exit(0)
```

**Edit: It seems this is a python-wide error, because my entire application is not capturing key events. It captures the mouse just fine, however.

Answer (score 0):

I think that not only do you need an .app bundle, but it needs to be run as the same user that is logged in to the display.  This is a security measure to help prevent the desktop equivalent of phishing.  There may be some way to get around that, such as temporarily becoming that user, or perhaps by working through some system security APIs that will allow the process full access to another user's display, but I don't know details.  Hopefully that will give you something to search for though.

Another possibility could be to split the UI into a separate process that is launched in user space upon some signal from your driver.  It could then get the credentials and send them back to the driver.